# invocation of dll from java , edit dll source code

Tags: java, c#, c++, dll, intellij-idea

I am using an open source jar from github and its running ok. While using the library API the program pops a message box and waits for user to click the ok button. I checked it via debugger and apparently a `dll` file in the native directory gets invoked and it is responsible for the messagebox, after clicking ok the output is what excepted. I guess my question is how to skip this message box or alternatively how can I just programmaticaly click the ok button so the program wont be halted until clicking the button. I try editing the `dll` file but its a binary code, and there is no way to edit a jar file and and re-compile it to work again, so I'm kinda stuck.

I believe that if I can watch the source code I can change the function itself and it should work but im unable to pull this off. I understand that the `dll` file before compilation probably was written in C, C++ or C# so I guess the only problem is getting to the dll file itself. i don`t beleive a sample code is required here.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have first a look in the code of the library if the DLL could be called without this popup.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly?... It's an open source project that includes a DLL in its distribution, but the source for the DLL is not posted? What is the DLL? And how is it called from the project's Java source?

Answer (score 0):

To decompile/reverse-engineer the DLL (if written in C#), you can use the free .NET decompiler from JetBrains: [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). If written in C/C++, it will be much harder to reverse engineer the DLL and I would recommend using some sort of test automation software. [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/) is a good paid one, and [SikuliX](http://www.sikulix.com/) is a free one that can probably accomplish what you need.